# Photon Server Register Custom Types

Tags: c#, sdk, server, photon

In the Photon Server examples for  [registering custom types](https://doc.photonengine.com/en/onpremise/current/reference/serialization-in-photon) , it says to use a function called `Protocol.TryRegisterCustomType(...)` but I am not sure if it exits since I cannot use it in code (I am using the free version of *Photon Server SDK*)... It is not even in the [Protocol documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/dotnet/current/class_exit_games_1_1_client_1_1_photon_1_1_protocol.html) nor in the [Photon Peer documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/dotnet/current/class_exit_games_1_1_client_1_1_photon_1_1_photon_peer.html) (which where `PhotonPeer.RegisterType(...)` exists).

Is  this function in some other namespace or what is the deal with this missing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer.RegisterType` for client and `Photon.SocketServer.Protocol.TryRegisterCustomType` for server.

Btw you can try ReSharper or other VS extension to automatically search for namespaces.